# Make WordPad properly open a UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoded file

Tags: utf-8, wordpad

When I try to open a file that has UTF-8 encoding, I get some junk characters.  I don't see anywhere in the open dialog to specify the encoding for the file.  I have seen various answers which talk about how to *save* as UTF-8 so Wordpad will properly recognize, however this file is from an external source and I didn't create it.  How can I get WordPad to correctly recognize the encoding?

Update: I read somewhere that maybe WordPad only supports UTF-16, not UTF-8.  I tried opening a file encoded in UTF-16 but when the file is opened, there is a space between every character and special characters still don't display correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### When I try to open a file that has UTF-8 encoding, I get some junk characters.

Your file needs to have a BOM (Byte Order Mark) at the beginning in order to specify the encoding.

> Try writing a BOM (Byte Order Mark) at the beginning of the file.
>   Chr(255) followed by Chr(254) denotes little-endian 16 bit encoding.
>
> [FAQ - UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 & BOM](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)

Source [Wordpad and Unicode](https://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/92451-Wordpad-and-Unicode)